# Setting checkbox values, using a dropdown lists value

Tags: php, html

Im having trouble setting the values of checkboxes. The values need to be the result of selecting first a dropdown option, which then upon a click return the value as a checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $area_of_education ?>">
```

Only returned a blank checkbox.

Comment: Is this a post refresh to the page? Also include more of your code pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well php is a server side script that runs before the page is loaded. So if anything is clicked on the client side it will not update the page already shown to the client, unless there is a post refresh. You could try to use Javascript or Jquery to get this effect however.

Now if this is a returned value to the checkbox then the value should be the selected value from the dropdown list it just won't show because it is an attribute of the checkbox.

try something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $area_of_education ?>"> <?php echo $area_of_education ?>
```

Comment: @user1185918 You're very welcome, also if you think my answer correctly solved you quest dont forget to check mine as the correct one.